# How to show an alert when we entered wrong secure code using Objective-C in iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a webservices url which appends with securecode. When I enter correct securecode for example to say abcd, then application will load. when I entered wrong secure code, I need to show alert as 'wrong securecode'. My code is here:

```
- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)Title:(int)tag
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:Title

                                                    message:msg
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    if(tag) 
        alertView.tag = tag;
    [alertView show];
}


-(IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {

    @try {

        if([[txtsecurecode text] isEqualToString:@""]  ) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Access code" :@"Login Failed!":0];
        } else {
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"txtsecurecode=%@",[txtsecurecode text]];

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my example.com/Accountservice/Security/ValidAccess?accesscode=%@&type=1",txtsecurecode.text]];

            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

responseData is the reference where I am getting response from the web services url.so below getting response, I need to keep alert.

How can I keep alert in this case showing alert when entered wrong secure code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code...

```
-(IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {

    @try {

        if([[txtsecurecode text] isEqualToString:@""]  ) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Access code" :@"Login Failed!":0];
        } else {
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"txtsecurecode=%@",[txtsecurecode text]];

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my example.com/Accountservice/Security/ValidAccess?accesscode=%@&type=1",txtsecurecode.text]];


            /*UPDATED*/
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


            if([responseData isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                [self alertStatus:@"Please enter valid Access code" :@"Login Failed!":0];
            }
            else
            {
                //Your code for handling the response data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For failure case, I am getting alert thats fine. but when I give correct secure code,I am getting '500-Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for' error.

Comment: just try to place the service url in your browser with the valid secure code and check whether the service returning proper response or not.  More over 500- internal server error completely belongs to server side issue not belongs to ios.

Comment: yeah, when I check the url in browser, it is returning proper response. where as In code, I am not getting the output in log.

Comment: Hai without modification code is working. Actually response is an url which need to access using web view. I wrote the code in else statement as If responseData is something which we required.by seeing on log I am getting the url too. but not loading the content of url in webView. showing error as described above...

Comment: now place the response url in the browser and check whether that url retunring data or not.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is done in where you get the response.

In the response you will have a variable notifying the success or Failure.

Check for that value.

- If the value is indicating success .Proceed  if it indicates
- Failure then show "authentication failed as alert.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need a tag when in fact you are actually naming a specific method.  Maybe, the code can be as simple as the following?

```
- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)Title {
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:Title
                                                message:msg
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alertView show];
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check response which comes from web-service data for valid & Invalid code.

You'll get in this method ::

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    value = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webdata mutableBytes] length:[webdata length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"==>%@", value);
    
    if ([value isEqualToString:@"Valid"]) {
       NSLog(@"Valid");
    }
    else {
       NSLog(@"Invlid");

       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:Title 
                                               message:msg
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alertView show];
    }
    
    [webData release];
    webData = nil;
    
    [connection release];
    connection = nil;
}
```

Based on 'value', you can check for your **Valid** & **Invalid** code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your response, whether it is giving your desired answer or not.

-- if its not giving a proper answer., you can show your alertView here., Else you can continue with your further logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])

    if ([responseString isEqualToString:@"Success"]) {
       NSLog(@"Success");
    }
    else {

       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:Title 
                                               message:msg
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alertView show];
    }

    [responseData release];
    responseData = nil;

    [connection release];
    connection = nil;
}
```